# Set up Apache + Tomcat + SSL, but don't know how to use SSL for non-Tomcat requests

Tags: apache-2.2

Title is a bit confusing, so here's some background: I have a Tomcat server running on 8080 that needed to be secured. I configured Apache to terminate SSL and proxy to Tomcat, like so (which I *think* I did correctly):

```
ProxyRequests       off
ProxyPreserveHost   on
ProxyPass           /jira   http://localhost:8080/jira
ProxyPassReverse    /jira   http://localhost:8080/jira

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    SSLEngine on

    ProxyPass           /   http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse    /   http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

This worked as expected, except now I want to secure other directories in my web server, for example a Mercurial repository. When I create said Directory and require SSL, the request gets forwarded to Tomcat (just like I told it to...which in this case is not what I want).

So my question is this: how do I change my configuration so I can only forward certain requests to the Tomcat server?

Updated solution per Shane's response:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    SSLEngine on

    ProxyPass / !
    ProxyPass           /jira   http://localhost:8080/jira
    ProxyPassReverse    /jira   http://localhost:8080/jira
</VirtualHost>
```

Made sense to do it this way, since then I'm only proxying the applications I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ProxyPass` exemptions before your existing configs to avoid proxying certain locations:

```
ProxyPass /location/to/not/proxy !
ProxyPass /other/location/to/not/proxy !
...
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```